# Generating checkboxes from database after failed form validation in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I'm creating a form with validation in CodeIgniter, and I have problem with mixing proccessing form with validation. In my form I have checkboxes that are generated from database. All works, when someone submit form without mistake (no validation failure), but after failed validation my checkboxes are not generated correctly (I have errors).

My Controller:

```
    public function form()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    /////////////////////////////////////////
    ////// MY PROCESSING CODE //////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////
    //Generating checkbocks from database
    $data['szkolenia'] = $this->Szkolenie_m->pobierz();

    //Validation
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('imie', 'Imię', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'Błąd: wypełnij powyższe pole');

    //After form submit
            if (!empty($_POST))
    {
    $konsultant = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $dane = array(
        'email1' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'imie' => $this->input->post('imie'),
        'nazwisko' => $this->input->post('nazwisko'),
        'nazwa_firmy' => $this->input->post('firma'),
        'konsultant_id' => $konsultant,
    );

    //Saving selected checkboxes into another db
    $boxes = $_POST['formChecks'];
    $N = count($boxes);
    $ostatni_id = $this->Osoby_m->ostatni_id();

    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
        $this->Osoby_m->nowy_wpis_formularz($boxes[$i]);    
        //echo $boxes[$i];      
    }       

    //Adding data to DB
    $this->Osoby_m->nowa_osoba($dane);  

    }   

    /////////////////////////////////////////
    ////// PROCESSING CODE END //////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('formularz', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('wyslano_formularz');
    }
}
```

My checkboxes in View:

```
  <?php foreach ($szkolenia as $szkolenie): ?>
  <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input id="szkolenie<?php echo $szkolenie->id; ?>" type="checkbox" name="formChecks[]" value="<?php echo set_value('formChecks[]'); ?>"> <?php echo $szkolenie->nazwa_szkolenia; ?></label>
        <br>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

After submiting this form with blank required input script doesnt reload checkboxes from database and display an error. This is happening event, when I put `$data['szkolenia'] = $this->Szkolenie_m->pobierz();` into

`if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('formularz', $data);
    }`

This is error I get:

[image]

Comment: can you add your view code??

Comment: Note that the PHP error states: `views/formularz.hp -> Line 81` thats where the wrong conversion took place.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju @Bonatti

I just added checkboxes code from view. This code works great without validation or with success validation. This is the 81 line:    `<label><input id="szkolenie<?php echo $szkolenie->id; ?>" type="checkbox" name="formChecks[]" value="<?php echo set_value('formChecks[]'); ?>"> <?php echo $szkolenie->nazwa_szkolenia; ?></label>`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load checkboxes on validation error,

use `set_checkbox('name', 'value');`

Like this,

```
set_checkbox('formChecks', 'value');
```

Getting error because, you are trying to echo an array.

Comment: Where I supposted to put this code? In my controller after `$data['szkolenia'] = $this->Szkolenie_m->pobierz();`?

Comment: instead of `set_value()`, use this

Comment: Now I don't have errors but - saving selected check boxes doesn't work: `$boxes = $_POST['formChecks'];
  $N = count($boxes);
  $ostatni_id = $this->Osoby_m->ostatni_id();
  
  for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
  {
   $this->Osoby_m->nowy_wpis_formularz($boxes[$i]); 
   echo $boxes[$i];  
  } `

and my validation doesn't return selected checkboxes